# ArcGIS labelling both ends of a polyline

Tags: arcgis, polyline

I have a shapefile of polylines with 2 fields IA and PA that I want to use as labels. I need the "start" of the line labelled with the values from IA field and the "end" of the line labelled with the value from the PA field.

I've found a way to do this using Label classes but I can't seem to set the label text to be horizontal as well as at the end of the line. Surely there must be a way to do this?!

Attached is a picture showing where I've got to, I need to values to be horizontal.
Thanks
[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fiehQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a tool **Feature Vertices To Point** and select Point type **Both Ends** in it. then there will be point on both ends that contains the data of your polyline, label them according to your need. In addition, you can set the symbol of your points to null to hide them.